# hide filename in url

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have tried hiding the filename in the URL using following code in the .htaccess file. But the File name is being displayed. Can anyone correct this code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: Not enough details. What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. Here i gave the static code. for example, my file name is testimonial.php and i changed it as testimonial.html. So in the a tag link you should give testimonial.html instead of testimonial.php. Then it ll work fine.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^testimonial.html /testimonial.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^aboutus.html /about_us.php [NC]
```